# duplication removal from randomly selected items from array does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The below code have four boxes I selected 3 items `randomly` from an array **items.**

I have placed the randomly selected item inside 4 boxes.

Class **box002** can be dragged and dropped to corresponding number in three boxes displayed. then `blue digit` in box dissappears.

I have a code to remove duplicates from randomly selected items,

> item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

but when i insert it into my code the rvalue() function does not rselect random values

How to solve this? And make make the randomly selected item without duplicates?

```js
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'
  },
  {
    label: '5',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'
  },
  {
    label: '6',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'
  },
  {
    label: '7',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'
  },
  {
    label: '8',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'
  },
  {
    label: '9',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
  },
  {
    label: '10',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10'
  }
];

var tempimages = [];
var array2 = [];
array2 = items.slice();

var backimgcount = 1;
var len = array2.length;

var item;
var displaycounter = 0;




var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/g/200/300'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}

function changeImage() {
  index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}


function rvalue() {


  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff66ff";
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #e3a89e ";

  }


  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

debugger;
  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    //item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    
    ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
    boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')'; 
    tempimages.push({
      data: item,
      index: randomIndex
    });

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;

  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;


}


function displayAllImages() {
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {

    rvalue();
  }


  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }


  var arr = tempimages;
  arr = shuffle(arr);

  item = arr.shift();
  image = document.getElementById('slide');
  image.src = item.data.url;
  image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;


};

$(function() {

  displayAllImages();

});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;



  if (x == y) {

    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
   
    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;
    array2.splice(arrayvalue, 1);


    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      changeImage();
    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {
    alert("WRONG PLACED");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;

}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size:contain;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.3vh;
  left: 72.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 23.0vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:30px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to remove duplicates is working.

The problem is that you overwrite the `item` variable.

```
item = array2[randomIndex];
item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
```

In the first line above,`item` is the randomly selected element of your `array2` array. After the second line is executed, `item` becomes **an array containing that element**.

From `Array.prototype.splice()` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value):

> **Return value**
>   An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

For example (mind the brackets):

```
item = array2[randomIndex];
console.log(item); // { "label": "2", "url": ... }
item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
console.log(item); // [ { "label": "2", "url": ... } ]
```

The rest of the code expects an object, not an array, so it fails. Since you don't need to make anything with that returned array you can simply switch to:

```
item = array2[randomIndex];
array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
```

Then, because you are already removing the elements in the random selection process, don't do it when the user drop `.box002` in the corresponding box. That means, delete the line below in your `drop()` function.

```
array2.splice(arrayvalue, 1);
```

```js
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'
  },
  {
    label: '5',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'
  },
  {
    label: '6',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'
  },
  {
    label: '7',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'
  },
  {
    label: '8',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'
  },
  {
    label: '9',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
  },
  {
    label: '10',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10'
  }
];

var tempimages = [];
var array2 = [];
array2 = items.slice();

var backimgcount = 1;
var len = array2.length;

var item;
var displaycounter = 0;




var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/g/200/300'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}

function changeImage() {
  index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}


function rvalue() {


  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff66ff";
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #e3a89e ";

  }


  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

debugger;
  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    
    ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
    boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')'; 
    tempimages.push({
      data: item,
      index: randomIndex
    });

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;

  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;


}


function displayAllImages() {
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {

    rvalue();
  }


  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }


  var arr = tempimages;
  arr = shuffle(arr);

  item = arr.shift();
  image = document.getElementById('slide');
  image.src = item.data.url;
  image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;


};

$(function() {

  displayAllImages();

});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;



  if (x == y) {

    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
   
    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;

    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      changeImage();
    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {
    alert("WRONG PLACED");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;

}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size:contain;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.3vh;
  left: 72.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 23.0vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:30px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great explantion verymuch understand the scenario, thanks for the documentation also.